# What Figure of Speech is used in phrases like "sugar mugar"?

Tags: grammar, literature, reduplication

There are combinations like *sugar mugar* that people use in their speech while the second word has no meaning and only adds a rhythm.
What is this called in English?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In linguistics, this sort of repetition is called **reduplication**, and the second half is sometimes called a **reduplicant**.  Reduplication is the most common term, but let's explore some more specific terms that are less common.

In your example, the reduplicant is altered, incorporating a special kind of prefix, and although there is no common term for this, a few linguists have called this a **duplifix**:

> **duplifix**: an element attached to the base that consists of both copied segments and fixed segments (= a mixture of affix and reduplicant)
>
> (*Understanding Morphology*, Haspelmath & Sims, p.326)

If we adopt this terminology, one common example would be the English duplifix (prefix) /ʃm/ (variously spelled *shm* or *schm*), and this process is sometimes called [***shm*-reduplication**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22shm+reduplication%22).  This particular duplifix is used to express a pejorative attitude toward the discourse topic – skepticism, dismissal, or similar sentiments:

> *Rene*: What are you doing? You promised me breakfast.
>
> *Brodie*: **Breakfast, shmreakfast**. Look at the score, for Christ's sake. It's only the second period and I'm up 12 to 2. Breakfasts come and go, Rene, but Hartford, "the Whale," they only beat Vancouver once, maybe twice in a lifetime.
>
> (transcript from the movie *Mall Rats*)

Here, *breakfast* is the discourse topic, and Brodie is expressing a pejorative, dismissive attitude toward this topic with *shm*-reduplication.

More generally, this category of reduplication is also known as [**echo reduplication**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22echo+reduplication%22), and this occurs in many languages.  In your example, *mugar* echoes *sugar*, but with the initial consonant replaced with /m/.  This might be the best term for your particular example; it doesn't imply any sort of pejorative meaning like *shm*-reduplication does.

Comment: Your answer is _neato-frito_.

Comment: @JR Totes magotes.

Comment: Some additional details of the secone example as a specific type of reduplication most closely associated with Yiddish: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication#Origins_and_sociolinguistic_distribution