# How to make "rhyming compounds" ( such as lovey-dovey, hubble-bubble, roly-poly)?

Tags: grammar, reduplication

I recently learned that there are some compound words in English that are called ["**rhyming compounds**"](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/rhyming_compounds01.html).
I'd like to know:

1- Are there any grammatical rules for making these compound words?

2- What are the different types/forms of such compound words? (I mean on what basis the second word is chosen: semantically, phonologically, or something else?)

3- Can we use them in formal conversations or contexts too?

Comment: Related: **[What Figure of Speech is used in phrases like “sugar mugar”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83435/what-figure-of-speech-is-used-in-phrases-like-sugar-mugar)**

Comment: Thanks,@CowperKettle. Do you mean that I can find the details by searching "reduplication"?

Comment: @Soudabeh: [Here's](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/rhyming_compounds01.html) a (non-exhaustive) list. Be aware that almost all such words are to some extent informal and/or "childish", except with words like *couscous, voodoo, jigsaw, seesaw* which have either been effectively "imported", or have been around for generations with no credible surviving ("formal") alternative. You're *very* unlikely to sound like a native speaker if you go out of your way to maximise use of such terms (*especially* if you try to make up your own! :)

Comment: I'm not sure, Soudabeh, I only thought that this is the mechanism that is at work here, and added the tag. For some reason I was never interested in the origin of such words, it seemed self-evident: a desire to create a compound that sounds 'cute'.

Comment: Thanks again, @CowperKettle.:)  Thanks to your first comment, I googled "reduplication" and  found some information about its types in : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There are no grammatical rules: you don't even have to use real words. It's more about making something that sounds right.

2) I am not sure what you mean by subtypes: maybe this document will answer your question. http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/rhyming_compounds01.html

3) Rhyming compounds are very informal, even intimate. You use them a lot with children, and people often use rhyming compounds to make up affectionate nicknames for their friends. I use such nicknames, but I would be embarrassed to reveal them in this context. They are probably best avoided in formal conversations, unless you have heard somebody else use the same one in the same context.

In the document that I referred to earlier, I have heard variations of many of the examples, and most of them seem pretty weak to me: I would not consider using even in informal conversation.

My personal favourites are the onomatopoeic 'yada-yada' which refers to meaningless talk, and 'wrongy bongy' which was coined by an Egyptian friend.

Comment: I linked to the same page in my comment. It's a very idiosyncratic list, with many entries that look very "non-standard" to me - quite apart from those I've never encountered, there's ***cha-ching*** (cash register sound) for what almost everyone else writes/says as ***ker-ching***, and ***klip-klop*** - which is astonishingly rare compared to ***clip-clop, clipclop***.

Comment: Sorry @FumbleFingers, we were writing at the same time. I agree, it's a weird list.

Comment: Their list of [broad categories](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/rhyming_compounds00.html) (Rhyming, Alliterative, Duplicative, Complex Rhyming) might be helpful to someone. Certainly the Yiddish Rhyming Compound Rule is pervasive in many sociolinguistic quarters (and most usages for *that* one are effectively one-offs; you might have trouble finding an exact duplicate usage elsewhere).