# Synonym of "classy" with a negative connotation

Tags: word-request

Depending on your point of view, we can take some charactristics as negative or positive e.g. *determined **->** stubborn, innocent **->** naive*.

My friends and I are looking for a disapproving word being used by people from low-class in society (probably a slang word) to describe a person who is **classy**.

For example, you go shopping with your friend and your friend suggests a design shirt and you say **humorously**,

> I'm not (a) [classy] (person).
>
> (Needless to say, classy is a positive word and I want a negative equivalent mostly used by people who lead a hard life)

Or someone asks a poor or a homeless guy if he uses dental floss. He answers,

> We're not [classy].

In my native language we use a word which almost means *"an obssessive princess"* by which we mean you're rich and really careful about your clothes or unimportant things.

Is there any adjective, *noun, or even a verb phrase* to describe such a person?

(Informal/slang words are really appreciated since we use this word informally in our language.)

Comment: I don't think it's pretentious to brush one's teeth and floss (we call it "dental hygiene") but you've used the word you're looking for: **pretentious**.

Comment: I know, I said it's used by low-class people who are obssessed with hard aspects of their lives so they see these thing as not really important things so they use 'classy' in a negative way. Do you recommend I should include this in my question more directly? And still 'pretentious' works here?

Comment: If we disregard the dental hygiene part and being upset because a car has splashed you with dirty water (people from any social background are entitled to this in the 21st century) I would go with the word [snob](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snob) for a negative connotation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a list question and answers will likely be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: What word is that? Because of all the descriptions so far, a summarized version might help to keep this focused.

Comment: OK, I hope my question is now clear. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the UK, [posh](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/posh) is used primarily by working class people. It is used by aspirational ones in a positive way, "we got dressed up all posh, like", but it can also have a derogatory meaning. If you offered a napkin to a proud-to-be-working-class man, he might reply

> Naa, I'm not posh, mate.

[ladida](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/la%E2%80%93di%E2%80%93da) is a mild expression of disapproval of somebody's affectations.

[poncy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ponce?q=poncy) is a working class way of saying "pretentious", and it's definitely derogatory. This might be used about the shirt:

> You won't catch me wearing a poncy shirt like that!

Comment: Great, that's the meaning I'm looking for. These are very helpful words. Do you happen to know American equivalents, too?

Comment: I'm BrE, so i can't report from personal experience. Highfalutin comes to mind: it's definitely AmE in origin.

Comment: Just to confirm that even a BBC-watching American like me would be very unlikely to use _"posh"_ and would never use _"poncy."_  The second word, _"ladida"_ isn't used, but _ladidadee_ is used to signify something like indifferent.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for confirming that. Derogatory terms for 'people not like us' tend to be quite local, as they need to identify specific traits in those people. At the opposite end of the scale, "trailer trash" would not work in the UK because we don't have trailer parks, and I'm guessing that CHAV (Council House and Violent) wouldn't work in the US because you don't have council houses.

Comment: What you call _council houses_ we call _projects._  There is definitely a stigma associated with being _from the projects,_ but I am not aware of a word similar to _Chav._   Maybe the incredible offensive _ghetto trash?_

Comment: Slight difference there -- what Americans call *projects*, Brits call *council estates* or *housing schemes*.  A *council house* is an individual property (possibly a flat/apartment in a block).

Comment: I don't think the folk etymology of *chav* coming from an acronym is widely-believed, but the word itself is very illustrative of 1990s Britain, and we have lots of similar ones, all derogatory words for working-class people, many of them very regional: *ned*, *schemie*, *scally* etc.  They're generally rude (although sometimes proudly used for self-labelling); but they lack the racist subtext that I think you get from *ghetto*.

Answer (score 4):

I think the term ***hoity-toity*** might work for you here:

> No, thanks; I'm no *hoity-toity* person with fancy designer clothes.

According to the [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hoity-toity) page, this reduplicative<sup>1</sup> term can be defined as:

> **hoity-toity** (*adj.*) Pretentiously self-important; pompous, self-important and snobbish.

A 2011 television show review used the term this way:

> *In the case of Roddy, it's discovered that he's an outcast.
>
>   He's a troubled kid at a fancy, **hoity-toity** high school.*

I've usually heard this term use pejoratively, which is what you're after, but it's not considered vulgar or profane. I think it would work well in light-hearted contexts.

---

<sup>1</sup>For more on reduplication, see [this ELL answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83435/what-figure-of-speech-is-used-in-phrases-like-sugar-mugar).

Answer (score 1):

**Lardy-dardy** meaning *excessively elegant*,*pretentious* can be used in some context.**Arty-farty** is *pretentious* but it is derogatory.